# Knob and tube wiring

Tags: electrical, knob-and-tube

I'm currently remodeling my 1876 home. Some upgrades have been made by just adding new breakers and wiring, but I've come to a room that runs its power through the old knob and tube wiring. I am going to install all new wire, fixtures, etc.

The old knob and tube system also powers the two rooms next to the one I'm currently remodeling. Can I cut the old wire and cap it off with a wire nut and tape until I can remove the remaining live knob and tube wiring in the house?

Comment: Knob-and-tube wiring actually meets code, believe it or not.. In some cases it's even better than Romex, as rodents chewing on Romex have actually caused house fires.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can but you must make sure that the ends that you cap off are still accessible if there is any chance they may become active (hot). I would recommend you cut back to a place such as an attic and make them safe from there.

Happy New Year.

Comment: This ^^, but don't be surprised if touching a little bit of knob and tube leads to outages elsewhere. You might be lucky enough to have circuits isolated to only a couple of rooms, but I wouldn't bet any money on it.